# Texturing in blender

Tags: unity, game-design, textures, blender, tree

I am texturing a tree in bender using the sappling add-on, when i put the tree bark texture (which is saved as .jpg) the texture looks stretched and wierd, ive used "Use UV for mapping" on the curve modifier and it still looks stretched. I have blender 2.75.

Thanks in advance.  :)

Comment: could you post an example image of how it looks stretched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this heaps of times myself, I found that one weird way of fixing it was to convert the curve to a mesh, then select all > U for unwrap > cube projection. I will look like a huge mess in the UV Image editor but actually looks really good in the 3d Viewport in terms of unwrapping! Another option is to use the space tree addon, which is very good:

http://www.blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?282550-A-new-tree-add-on

And the newly released addon called The Grove, expensive but spectacular:

https://www.thegrove3d.com/

Comment: Thanks, my doubt is, to convert a curve to a mesh do i have to be in edit mode and then press curve and convert ? The rest i undestand, its like adding a texture to any buiding.

Comment: To convert go to object mode > alt + c > convert curve to mesh.

Comment: Thans, finally did it, now i can sell my asset,

Comment: No worries, glad it worked out!